# How can I share the url I got at runtime?

Tags: xcode, swift

Hi I am making a web browser app in witch the user could share with a share sheet the current url link (witch changes depending on what website the user is on)I am using the code below, the problem I have is that the share sheet opens but instead showing the app logos (mail, Facebook etc ) it only displays "more" how could I solve this problem? thanks !

```
@IBAction func shareweb(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    if let currentURL = WebView.request?.URL!.absoluteString
    {
        let objectsToShare = [WebView]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to share the WebView object itself. Instead, you want to share the URL. Something like:

```
if let currentURL = WebView.request?.URL
{
    let objectsToShare = [currentUrl]
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note that instead of calling `absoluteString` on the URL, I'm sending the URL object itself.

There's also a great tutorial on `UIActivityViewController` on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/).